# C# fileattachment content to string

Tags: c#, email, exchange-server, attachment, exchangewebservices

I am trying to get the content from an attachment on an email. I am able to read the email and all of its attributes. The attachment is a text file (.txt). How would i grab the actually text content of the attachment? Below is a section of my code showing how i grab each email and then get its attributes and store them in the findResults list. Something like fileAttachment.Name would give me the name of the attachment. fileAttachment.content.tostring() will only show me system.Byte[].

```
FindItemsResults<Item> findResults = service.FindItems(fid1, new ItemView(int.MaxValue));
service.LoadPropertiesForItems(from Item item in findResults select item, PropertySet.FirstClassProperties);

foreach (Item item in findResults)
{
    String body = "";
    #region attachments
    if (ReadAttachments == "1")
    {
        EmailMessage message = EmailMessage.Bind(service, item.Id, new PropertySet(BasePropertySet.IdOnly, ItemSchema.Attachments));

        foreach (Attachment attachment in message.Attachments)
        {
            if (attachment is FileAttachment)
            {
                FileAttachment fileAttachment = attachment as FileAttachment;

                // Load the file attachment into memory and print out its file name.
                fileAttachment.Load();

                String attachbody = fileAttachment.Content.ToString();

                if (attachbody.Length > 8000)
                {
                    attachbody = attachbody.Substring(0, 8000);
                }
                Console.writeline(attachbody);
                #endregion

            }
        }
    }
    #endregion
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's because it is an array of bytes you'll have to use a StreamReader to get it

```
var stream = new System.IO.MemoryStream(fileAttachment.Content);
var reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(stream, UTF8Encoding.UTF8);
var text = reader.ReadToEnd();
```

Comment: glad I could help, also fileAttachment might already include a Stream in that case you don't need to create a MemoryStream just use that one, and you should close the reader when you are finish using it (or use, using).

Comment: But here if I tried to print it to console like Console.Write(text) then it is showing some symbolic results with sound. Is it some kind of error or I am missing something??

Comment: But it is not working for .doc .xls files. It is showing some symbolic results. It is working for .txt file.